# Y is $f_t$-related to Y implies $f_t(g_s(p)=g_s(f_t(p))$ for all p$\in M$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I saw this claim, but stuck on this for a long time:
$X,Y\in \Gamma(TM$) are two complete vector fields with flows {$f_t$},{$g_s$}, then 
Y is $f_t$-related to Y implies  $f_t(g_s(p)=g_s(f_t(p))$ for all p$\in M$.

Comment: See Theorems 9.42 and 9.44 in my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_ (2nd ed.).

Comment: @JackLee, thank you, that's really helpful.

Comment: @JackLee I have another question,Suppose to vector field V, $a$ is its critical point, how to show there exits a NBHD V s.t. integral curve exists on [-1,1] for all the points from V? I just don't know where to start, could you give me some hints? Thank you!

Comment: I'll add a hint to your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460474/the-integral-curve-of-the-points-around-critical-point-of-the-vector-field).